# Odoo ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'PyPDF2

Tags: pypdf, odoo-15

I just started learning odoo and got this error, while I have utils and PyPDF2 installed, I am using python 3.8, PyPDF2 2.11 .1, utils 1.0.1, I need your help, many thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use PyPDF2 1.28.6 or older. Odoo is not compatible with PyPDF2 2.x

Answer (score 2):

I installed odoo a week ago and have faced the same problem. After checking a number of forums with a number of suggestions, installing and uninstalling Python programs, and a lot of other things, I checked the installation path. I found out that there is a "_utils.py" file, but no "utils.py", so I made a copy of the first one and named it as the second one. Voilá.

Comment: This solution is referring to python3-pypdf2 package, not Odoo. To find the path, you can run `dpkg -L python3-pypdf2 | grep -i _utils.py`

I found 2 paths, and made symlinks pointing to the _utils.py file `sudo ln -sf _utils.py utils.py` and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Can you try chmod for your addons first

```
sudo chmod -R /path_addons
```

or in windows change security for folder

for pypdf2
can you try to reinstall pypdf2

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pypdf2
```

or

```
pip3 install Pypdf2
```

Answer (score 0):

use this
pip install -r odoo/requirement.txt